# To "fling oneself on his/her face" -- expression

Tags: idioms, expressions, meaning-in-context

What does this phase "fling oneself on his/her face" mean in the following context?

> Winston promptly flung himself on his face.

Comment: Does a dictionary help? [[flung himself](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fling?q=flung+himself)] Admittedly there is a subtle difference between "flung herself on his bed" as per the example there and "flung himself on his face". If the dictionary doesn't help, please edit the question to explain why not.

Comment: Look up *flung*, *himself*, & *face* in the dictionary, seriously.

Comment: It it a weird expression so don't be so patronising, @Kris. Taken literally, one would expect the person smashing his face into the ground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a rocket bomb about to hit, Winston hits the deck to not be hit by flying debris.

[image: Orwell, Nineteen Eighty-Four]

Comment: That is not an idiom, not a set phrase or a colloquialism. As such it comes down to literary interpretation. OT.

Comment: @Kris, I seem to recall that in books of the time (Orwell wrote *Nineteen Eighty-Four* in 1949) to “fling oneself on one's face” was more or less a set phrase for ducking down or getting to cover.  So I disagree with your comment.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flung+himself+on+his+face&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cflung%20himself%20on%20his%20face%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @jwpat7 To see how more or how less a set phrase something is, mplungjan's ngram helps: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flung+himself+on+his+face&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cflung%20himself%20on%20his%20face%3B%2Cc0 vs. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=over+the+moon%2Csee+the+light&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cover%20the%20moon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csee%20the%20light%3B%2Cc0